# does implicit pointer conversion occur during assignment?

Tags: c++, pointer-conversion

For e.g.

```
int x = 3;
float * ptr = (float*)&x;  // here compiler does not implicitly do conversion, but we have to manually convert to float*
```

so my question is, why here we don't need to manually convert it.

```
Base_Class * ptr = Derived_Class pointer;
```

is here implicit conversion occuring ?

Comment: Yes, derived pointer -> base pointer conversion can happen implicitly. Unlike `int *` -> `float *`, because those are unrelated types.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> here compiler does not implicitly do conversion

Because `int` and `float` are [unrelated types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20930858/type-conversion-in-c-related-and-unrelated-types). Accessing one as if it's the other (type punning) is Undefined Behavior.

> Why is here implicit conversion occurring

Because accessing a derived object via a pointer of type base is a fundamental mechanism by which [runtime polymorphism](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5854581/polymorphism-in-c) works.